# Terminal mode for Vim 8?

Tags: vim, neovim

Is there a terminal mode (similar to in NeoVim) for Vim 8 yet? I know that Vim 8 has new async features, which makes it possible to make an async terminal feature in Vim (like Neovim already has), so curious if anyone is already trying to do that.

Comment: Try http://www.vim.org

Comment: @romainl yeah, right, like I'll be able to find the answer there before I barf everywhere from the design of the site. It will be better for the answer to live here. Also searching for "terminal" in the vim.org search box didn't really help.

Comment: Nothing on the first page: https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Avim.org%20terminal

Comment: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=terminal&script_type=utility&order_by=creation_date&direction=descending&search=search

Comment: @romainl There's no results there. If you sort those results by date, you'll see there's none that are new enough to use the new async features.

Comment: You have your answer.

Comment: You could always just use Neovim?

Comment: @swalladge haha yeah, that's what I'm doing. :) I was just curious to see if Vim was catching up (or not).

Answer (score 4):

Vim 8.0.0693 is the first of an ongoing series of patches ("terminal emulator support") that implements this. If you're willing to compile Vim yourself and work with alpha-grade software, go right ahead. The latest source code and runtime files can be downloaded via FTP or retrieved from GitHub; see [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/sources.php) for details. As this feature is under development, you can still influence it and help the contributors by reporting bugs.

In case you just want to use a final version, you have to wait for the next Vim release (version 8.1?), or switch to Neovim.